# Regular expression that finds and replaces non-ascii characters with Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to change some characters that are not ASCII to '_'.
For example,

```
Tannh‰user -> Tannh_user
```

- If I use regular expression with Python, how can I do this?
- Is there better way to do this not using RE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated for Python 3:**

```
>>> 'Tannh‰user'.encode().decode('ascii', 'replace').replace(u'\ufffd', '_')
'Tannh___user'
```

First we create byte string using `encode()` - it uses UTF-8 codec by default. If you have byte string then of course skip this encode step.
Then we convert it to "normal" string using the ascii codec.

This uses the property of UTF-8 that all non-ascii characters are encoded as sequence of bytes with value >= 0x80.

---

**Original answer – for Python 2:**

How to do it using built-in `str.decode` method:

```
>>> 'Tannh‰user'.decode('ascii', 'replace').replace(u'\ufffd', '_')
u'Tannh___user'
```

(You get `unicode` string, so convert it to `str` if you need.)

You can also convert `unicode` to `str`, so one non-ASCII character is replaced by ASCII one. But the problem is that `unicode.encode` with `replace` translates non-ASCII characters into `'?'`, so you don't know if the question mark was there already before; see solution from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

---

Another way, using `ord()` and comparing value of each character if it fits in ASCII range (0-127) - this works for `unicode` strings and for `str` in utf-8, latin and some other encodings:

```
>>> s = 'Tannh‰user' # or u'Tannh‰user' in Python 2
>>> 
>>> ''.join(c if ord(c) < 128 else '_' for c in s)
'Tannh_user'
```

Comment: it is not percent % but ‰ . Not sure it is still ascii. Is it?

Comment: It's U+2030 character, per mille sign (not in ASCII).

Answer (score 16):

```
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', '_', theString)
```

This will work if theString is unicode, or a string in an encoding where ASCII occupies values 0 to 0x7F (latin-1, UTF-8, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question

```
'[\u0080-\uFFFF]'
```

will match any UTF-8 character not in the range of the first 128 characters

```
re.sub('[\u0080-\uFFFF]+', '_', x)
```

will replace any sequence of consecutive nonascii characters with an underscore

Comment: happy to see someone answered the question!  even if at the bottom of the list

Answer (score 5):

Using Python's support for character encodings:

```
# coding: utf8
import codecs

def underscorereplace_errors(exc):
  return (u'_', exc.end)

codecs.register_error('underscorereplace', underscorereplace_errors)

print u'Tannh‰user'.encode('ascii', 'underscorereplace')
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather just call `ord` on every character in the string, 1 by 1.  If `ord([char]) >= 128` the character is not an ascii character and should be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

With the magical regex `[ -~]` one can solve it:

```
import re
re.sub(r"[^ -~]", "_", "Tannh‰user")
# 'Tannh_user'
```

---

Explanation:

- The ascii characters are the symbols [ranging from " " to "~"](https://www.ascii-code.com/) - hence `[ -~]` captures all ascii chars
- By appending `^`we can capture all non-ascii characters
- The rest is now a formality

Answer (score 1):

if you know which characters you want to replace, you can apply string methods

```
mystring.replace('oldchar', 'newchar')
```

Comment: -1: first, it should be `ord(item)>127`. Then, think what your code does for this string: `'\xa0'*1000`.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ The downvoted part has been eliminated. Note that although you are right and it could not manage the '\xa0' type representation, it worked perfectly with any one-char printable symbols that I understood was the type of strings the OP was fighting with. Also note that another post suggested the very same approach.

Comment: I removed my downvote, but I can't find any other answer that: for *every applicable* character in the input string, replace the *whole input string*. In my `'\xa0'*1000` example, your code performed the whole `mystring` substitution a thousand times, 999 times of which unnecessarily. If you disagree with this, then given `astr='hello'; c=0`, what is the value of c after this loop: `for char in astr: c+= 1; astr=''`? I say it would be 5, you might think it would be 1.

Comment: Brian's answer proposes the same approach: to check the value of ord() for each char in the string and replacing it if it is beyond 127. I understand your point now. After your first comment I realized that my code was not working with mystring = '\xa0' because it was checking '\', then 'x'... So I though this was your point. Now I understantd you refered to another thing I missed: the string in the for loop is unaltered during the search process so that repeated characters are checked even after they have been already replaced in the variable inside the loop. Not very efficient. Thanks!