# how regex in Python3 deal with diacritics?

Tags: regex, unicode, python-3.x

I try to parse with *Python3* and the *re* module strings using the pattern "(c,c,c)" where c is one character to be choosed among (a,b,ë,ɪ̈ ). I wrote something like that :

```
src="(a,b,ɪ̈)"
pattern = "[abëɪ̈]"
for r in re.finditer( '\({0},{0},{0}\)'.format(pattern), src ):
    print( r.group() )
```

But the regex doesn't work with ɪ̈; Python analyses  ɪ̈ as made of two characters (ɪ + diairesis), id est ɪ plus a diacritic : the regex doesn't know how to read "(a,b,ɪ̈)". I haven't the same problem with ë; Python analyses ë as one character and my regex is able to read "(a,b,ë)", giving the expected answer.
I tried to use a normalize approach thanks to unicodedata.normalize('NFD', ...) applied to *src* and *pattern*, unsuccessfully.

How shall I solve this problem ? It would be nice to help me !

PS : I fixed some typos thanks to *pythonm*.

Comment: you forgot the : on third line and swept chrs on second

Comment: Take a look at this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758921/regular-expression-that-finds-and-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-python).

Comment: this works: `re.findall( r'\({0},{0},ɪ̈\)'.format("[abëɪ̈]"), "(a,b,ɪ̈)")` -> `['(a,b,ɪ̈)']`. Note: `ɪ̈` is matched literally not via `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `|` to workaround it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

print(re.findall(r'\({0},{0},{0}\)'.format("(?:[abë]|ɪ̈)"), "(a,b,ɪ̈)"))
# -> ['(a,b,ɪ̈)']
```

The above treats `ɪ̈` as two characters:

```
re.compile(r'[abë]|ɪ̈', re.DEBUG)
```

output:

```
branch 
  in 
    literal 97
    literal 98
    literal 235
or
  literal 618 
  literal 776
```

Comment: An interesting answer to my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I obviously misunderstood what the regular expression was intended to be. Good answer.