# Creating custom extensions to a regular expression engine

Tags: python, regex, dsl

Is there any easy way to go about adding custom extensions to a
Regular Expression engine? (For Python in particular, but I would take
a general solution as well).

It might be easier to explain what I'm trying to build with an
example.  Here is the use case that I have in mind:

I want users to be able to match strings that may contain arbitrary
ASCII characters.  Regular Expressions are a good start, but aren't
quite enough for the type of data I have in mind.  For instance, say I
have data that contains strings like this:

```
<STX>12.3,45.6<ETX>
```

where `<STX>` and `<ETX>` are the Start of Text/End of Text characters
0x02 and 0x03.  To capture the two numbers, it would be very
convenient for the user to be able to specify any ASCII
character in their expression. Something like so:

```
\x02(\d\d\.\d),(\d\d\.\d)\x03
```

Where the "\x02" and "\x03" are matching the control characters and
the first and second match groups are the numbers.  So, something like
regular expressions with just a few domain-specific add-ons.

How should I go about doing this?  Is this even the right way to go?
I have to believe this sort of problem has been solved, but my initial
searches didn't turn up anything promising.  Regular Expression have
the advantage of being well known, keeping the learning curve down.

A few notes:

- I am not looking for a fixed parser for a particular protocol - it needs to be general and user configurable
- I really don't want to write my own regex engine
- Although it would be nice, I am not looking for "regex macros" where I create shortcuts for a handful of common expressions. (perhaps a follow-up question...)
- Bonus: Have you heard of any academic work, i.e "Creating Domain Specific search languages"

---

**EDIT:** Thanks for the replies so far, I hadn't realized Python `re` supported  arbitrary ascii chars.  However, this is still not quite what I'm looking for. Here is another example that hopefully give the breadth of what I want in the end:

Suppose I have data that contains strings like this:

```
$\x01\x02\x03\r\n
```

Where the `123` forms two 12-bit integers (0x010 and 0x023).  So how could I add syntax so the user could match it with a regex like this:

```
\$(\int12)(\int12)\x0d\x0a
```

Where the `\int12`'s each pull out 12 bits.  This would be handy if trying to search for packed data.

Comment: I think this may work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759009/1709129 just remove the caret

Answer (score 2):

`\x` escapes are already supported by the Python regular expression parser:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\x02(\d\d\.\d),(\d\d\.\d)\x03')
>>> regex.match('\x0212.3,45.6\x03')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f551b0c9a48>
```