# python 2 get the number between Chinese characters from the urllib2 response result

Tags: python, urllib2, encode

I want to get the digit 805 between the html tag using urllib2 from a web page.

```
<span class="count">(共805张)</span>
```

Here is the python code I wrote to get the number:

```
url = "https://movie.douban.com/celebrity/1044996/photos/"
request = urllib2.Request(url,headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
pattern1 = re.compile(r'<span\sclass="count">(.*?)</', re.S)
result1 = re.search(pattern1, content)
total_num = result1.group(1)
total_num = total_num
```

But when I print the total_num, the console shows:

```
u'(\u5171805\u5f20)'
```

How can I get the number 805 expect using regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

If your html tag is always like this form:

```
<span class="count">(共805张)</span>
```

Which means the number is between two non latin characters and `'('` and `')'` you can use this pattern:

```
import re
a = <span class="count">(共805张)</span>
# This will work if theString is unicode, 
# or a string in an encoding where ASCII 
# occupies values 0 to 0x7F (latin-1, UTF-8, etc.)
final = re.findall('\([^\x00-\x7F]+(\d+)[^\x00-\x7F]+\)', a)

print final
```

Output:

```
['805']
```

**PS:** Credit to this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759009/3926995) with some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your regex by this one:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'<span\sclass="count">[^<\d]*(\d+)[^<\d]*</', re.S)
```

This way, the group will only match the number, and not the other characters around it.