# strip out non valid and non-ascci character from my string in Python

Tags: python, regex, ascii

Trying to format this string and strip out the non-ascii characters

```
import re 
text = '<phone_number><![CDATA[0145236243 <0x0C><0x05><0x4>
```

[image: ]]]>'
    clean = re.sub('[^\x00-\x7f]',"", text)

This does not seem to do the job properly.Does someone have a proper solution. I have also uploaded a file in case stackoverflow has formatted the non-ascci characters.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: something like this text =  '<contact_number><![CDATA[07744454]]></contact_number>'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python)

Comment: all the characters in you example are [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) char

Comment: You dont have have non-ascii characters in your text. You just have characters and numbers. Also your expected out contains contact_number and should be phone_number but I assume that is a typo

Comment: this i meant, slackoverflow stripped out the non-ASCII text = '<phone_number><![CDATA[0145236243  <0x0C><0x05><0x4>
] ]></phone_number>'

Comment: Ok did you have a look at the link I provided? Did it help?

Comment: Yes, i did , but seems that it wasn't the same problem. I have tried the solution.But still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very generic one. But the below solution might work for you

```
''.join([i for i in text.split() if('<0x') not in i])#'<phone_number><![CDATA[0145236243]]></phone_number>'
```

Using regex

```
 re.sub('(<0x\w*>)|\s',"", text) # '<phone_number><![CDATA[0145236243]]></phone_number>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This link also has a similar solution for all non UTF-8 characters. [Regular expression that finds and replaces non-ascii characters with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758921/regular-expression-that-finds-and-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-python)

You can try using str.encode() and str.decode() for this purpose.

Then you can replace them.