# Unicode error when trying to remove non-ascii chars

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I am parsing csv files and would like to remove non-ascii characters when they appear. Actually, I only need digits, but when I try to remove non-digit characters, I get an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

I have the following function:

```
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return ''.join(re.findall("\d+", str(text)))
```

Also tried (just to remove non-ascii chars):

```
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return ''.join(i for i in str(text) if ord(i)<128)
```

When I print the result of the following, I get the correct result (for both functions)

```
print(remove_non_ascii('E-Mail Adresse des Empfängers'))
```

However, when I apply the function to the dataframe column `df[col] = df[col].apply(remove_non_ascii)`, I get the `UnicodeEncodeError`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression that finds and replaces non-ascii characters with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758921/regular-expression-that-finds-and-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-python)

Comment: Not all digits in Unicode are ASCII, btw. That said, your question is off-topic because it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:
You need to `import string` and change the function to

```
setV = set(string.printable)
return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in setV, text))
```

This would remove all characters not in the set

Just noticed you put that you only need digits. Heres a more useful solution without the need to import string:

```
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    setV = set("1234567890")
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in setV, text))
```

Comment: Thanks, Second answer works perfectly. Just need to change set = set("1234567890") to  setV = set("1234567890"), otherwise it gives error local variable referenced before assignement.

Comment: Oops, my mistake