# replacing special characters from string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am having raw input in text format having special characters in string.I want to change these special character from strings so that after running code there will not be any special character in it.

[image]

[image]

I tried to write below code.I am not sure whether it is right or wrong.

```
def avoid(x):
#print(x)
#value=[]
for ele in range(0, len(x)):
    
    p=invalidcharch(ele)
    #value.append(p)
      #value=''.join(p)
    print(p)    
return p
def invalidcharch(e):
items={"ä":"a","ç":"c","è":"e","º":"","Ã":"A","Í":"I","í":"i","Ü":"U","â":"a","ò":"o","¿":"","ó":"o","á":"a","à":"a","õ":"o","¡":"","Ó":"O","ù":"u","Ú":"U","´":"","Ñ":"N","Ò":"O","ï":"i","Ï":"I","Ç":"C","À":"A","É":"E","ë":"e","Á":"A","ã":"a","Ö":"O","ú":"u","ñ":"n","é":"e","ê":"e","·":"-","ª":"a","°":"","ü":"u","ô":"o"} 

for i, j in items.items():
    e = e.replace(i, j)
return e

for col in df.columns:
 df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x:avoid(x))
```

but in above code I am unable to store whole string in variable p.I need to store whole string value in p so that it will store replace cell value.
Data containing mix datatype values like string integer.

**col A**
Junto à Estação de Carcavelos;
Bragança
Situado en el núcleo de Es Caló de Sant Agustí frente al Hostal Rafalet.
Cartão MOBI.E
R. Conselheiro Emídio Navarro (frente ao ISEL)

**After chnage**
Junto a Estacao de Carcavelos;
Braganca
Situado en el nucleo de Es Calo de Sant Agusti frente al Hostal Rafalet.
Cartao MOBI.E
R. Conselheiro Emidio Navarro (frente ao ISEL)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there the input and output dataframe in text form (so we can copy-paste it)?

Comment: check out this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/13357061

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Achille Huet's comment that links [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string), you can use this on a pandas dataframe column like this:

```
import unidecode
df['col A'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda x: unidecode.unidecode(x))
```

OR

```
import unidecode
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x: unidecode.unidecode(x))
```

However, since you have already created the special characters dictionary, you can use it:

Just create a dictionary `special_chars` and `replace` the values on the entire dataframe by passing `regex=True`. This should also be faster. I don't know if there is a faster solution using unicode. It also depends on what you are doing with it. If sending to a .csv file for example, I believe there is a parameter in `to_csv()` as well, but I am not sure if that is relevant:

```
special_chars = {"ä":"a","ç":"c","è":"e","º":"","Ã":"A","Í":"I","í":"i","Ü":"U","â":"a","ò":"o","¿":"",
"ó":"o","á":"a","à":"a","õ":"o","¡":"","Ó":"O","ù":"u","Ú":"U","´":"","Ñ":"N",
"Ò":"O","ï":"i","Ï":"I","Ç":"C","À":"A","É":"E","ë":"e","Á":"A","ã":"a","Ö":"O",
"ú":"u","ñ":"n","é":"e","ê":"e","·":"-","ª":"a","°":"","ü":"u","ô":"o"}

df.replace(special_chars, regex=True)
```

Comment: This is really awesome, did not know that replace takes a dict.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`Series.str.translate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html) which is equivalent to [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) + [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in python.

```
converter = str.maketrans(items) # `items` is special chars dict.
df['colA'].str.translate(converter)

0                                              Junto a Estacao de Carcavelos;
1                                                                    Braganca
2    Situado en el nucleo de Es Calo de Sant Agusti frente al Hostal Rafalet.
3                Cartao MOBI.E R. Conselheiro Emidio Navarro (frente ao ISEL)
Name: col A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html) module:

```py
import unicodedata

df["col A"] = df["col A"].apply(
    lambda x: unicodedata.normalize("NFD", x)
    .encode("ascii", "ignore")
    .decode("utf-8")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                      col A
0                                            Junto a Estacao de Carcavelos;
1                                                                  Braganca
2  Situado en el nucleo de Es Calo de Sant Agusti frente al Hostal Rafalet.
3              Cartao MOBI.E R. Conselheiro Emidio Navarro (frente ao ISEL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understood what you are trying to achieve, but you can try something like

```py
items={"ä":"a","ç":"c","è":"e","º":"","Ã":"A","Í":"I","í":"i","Ü":"U","â":"a","ò":"o","¿":"","ó":"o","á":"a","à":"a","õ":"o","¡":"","Ó":"O","ù":"u","Ú":"U","´":"","Ñ":"N","Ò":"O","ï":"i","Ï":"I","Ç":"C","À":"A","É":"E","ë":"e","Á":"A","ã":"a","Ö":"O","ú":"u","ñ":"n","é":"e","ê":"e","·":"-","ª":"a","°":"","ü":"u","ô":"o"} 

df = pd.DataFrame([
    'abcä',
    'Ãbcd12345'
], columns=['colA'])

df['colA'] = df['colA'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', lambda x: items.get(x.group(0)) or '_', regex=True)

df
```

```
    colA
0   abca
1   Abcd12345
```

For `r'[^\x00-\x7F]` check [Regular expression that finds and replaces non-ascii characters with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758921/regular-expression-that-finds-and-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply with the following part of code.

```
for i in df.columns:

    df[i] = df[i].replace(items, regex=True)
```